# i need fix select form on php code

Tags: php, explode

Hello I need to fix a problem on my PHP code. When I write the value `name=""` and `id=""` aren't found. Here's the code:

```
<?php
    $tipos= $eachoption['option_value'];
    $categorias='';
    $cats = explode(",",$tipos);
    echo "<select name=\"option_<?php echo $eachoption['option_id'];?>[]\" id=\"<?php echo $_POST['option_'.$eachoption['option_id']][$i];?>\">";

    foreach($cats as $cat){
        $cat = trim($cat);
        $categorias .= "<option>". $cat ."</option>";
    }
    echo $categorias;
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Thanks! I think that maybe is for `"` or `'` inside echo.

Comment: Open the page in a browser and look at the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP syntax is incorrect. You cannot embed PHP-within-PHP. e.g.

```
<?php
$foo = "<?php echo 'bar' ?>";
```

will **NOT** execute that `echo` call. You are assigning the literal characters `<`, `?`, `p`, etc... to a string.

Since you're using double-quoted strings, you don't need the echoes for simple variable insertions at all:

```
echo "<select name=\"option_{$eachoption['option_id']}[]\" id=\"" . $_POST['option_'.$eachoption['option_id']][$i]; . "\">";
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

note that the second $_POST does require breaking out of string mode, since you're dynamically creating the array key.